# How to change to a subdirectory and run an exe using a bat file in a Windows 7 system?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cd

Using a bat file, I want to change to a sub directory of folder which bat file is in, and run `my_application.exe` in that directory,

I try:

```
cd /d %cd%\my subdirectory
START %~dp0my_application.exe
```

But it doesn't work, it says it can't find my_application.exe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just indicate to `start` command what program to start and what should be the starting folder for it.

Without the `cd` command, it can be written as

```
start "" /d "%~dp0my_subdirectory" "my_application.exe"
```

if the `my_application.exe` is located in the subdirectory, or

```
start "" /d "%~dp0my_subdirectory" "%~dp0my_application.exe"
```

if the application is located in the same folder as the batch file.

`start` command take the first quoted parameter as the title for the new process. To avoid problems, a empty string (`""`) is included in command as the title.

Comment: The first start command using /d specifies the working directory so the executable doesn't require a full path to be specified.  That will simplify the command.

Comment: I've been looking for this solution for awhile. This solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
cd /d "%~dp0my_subdirectory"
start "" my_application.exe
```

or just:

```
start "" "%~dp0my_subdirectory\my_application.exe"
```